# Taking particular slides from mutilple pptx fles to from a new pptx file in php

Tags: php, powerpoint

My requirement is to make new pptx file by particular slides from multiple pptx files by using php,PHP Presentation can not be used for this.I tried Apache POI, it is much difficult,If any body can help me out, you can share your code.

Comment: do you even know that you will have internet access when you open the pptx?

Comment: It may well cost more to automate this than to do it manually

Comment: I have to cinsider both cases,with or with out internet

Comment: No one here to help, still stuck in this problem